# How many java semaphores instances can be created?

Tags: java, semaphore

I am using semaphore to signal the producer thread that another (consumer) thread has completed the shared data/object processing. But is there a limit for overall amount of semaphores instances I could create? I’d like to understand, is it ok to use such a synchronization for a large (hundreds of thousands) number of objects?
Please notice, it's another question - not about "what is the maximum number of permits semaphore could have", so ity is not a duplicate.
Thank you

Comment: I think the OP means how many instances of Semaphore can they create.

Comment: Why? Why not use a queue?

Comment: How could producer thread understand, message has been processed?

Comment: I supposed it’s clear, sorry. Edited question to clarify

Comment: Isnt a `Future` better for this ?

Comment: Semaphore is much simpler as i need to wait for processing result in the same method that produced a shared object

Comment: Hey, I didn’t ask for maximum permits, i asked about maximum instances! It’s a different question, do you understand that??? Wtf...

Comment: Can you share more details? What exactly do you mean by "maximum instances"?

Comment: @NicoHaase new Semaphore();

Comment: That's a single instance - so what's your question about this?

Comment: @NicoHaase Sorry, I don't understand, are you kidding or what?
Vector <Semapthore> v=new Vector();
while(true) v.add(new Semaphore());

Comment: @NicoHaase there's an answer and discussion below, just read it, and everything will be clear

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's undefined how many object instances you can create in Java. That depends on available memory.
It's undefined how `Semaphore` is implemented. If your platform imposes a limit it is probably higher than the hundreds of thousands you're proposing.

You can obviously just try it! Write a stub program that just allocates Semaphores and puts them in an ArrayList (to avoid them getting garbage collected) and see what happens.

Hundreds of thousands it not a 'scary' number in most environments but there are parsimonious ways of managing the object populations. For example, 'lazy initialisation'. Allocating a `Semaphore` on first acquire (or release if doing count up) and nulling the reference when it reaches zero is a a potential strategy for only having instances that 'in play' is a possibility if you need lots of 'logical' semaphores by in practice few of them will have a non-default (e.g. zero) number of permits in circulation.

Comment: Usually ipc semaphores amount is limited in the most oses, I understand these semaphores ain’t ipc, but asked to be sure. Thank you!

Comment: @BbIKTOP: I've corrected my answer. I wasn't aware of a limit and have created millions of mutexes and never got stuck. What I do know is that the Object monitor (that all objects have!) is typically 'lazy initialised'. That's half parsimonious! Objects are allocated without a monitor and one is allocated if they need it - but never unallocated.
If the JVM is using an OS construct 1-for-1 with Semaphore I'll be surprised if it isn't doing something similar. But you of course could anyway.

Comment: @BbIKTOP Here's some code that creates, acquires, checks and releases 10,000,000 Semaphores very quickly in a toy environment: https://ideone.com/KHmqpO
That doesn't prove anything but it suggests you don't have a problem.
I've made sure to release all permits before the Semaphore is inaccessible.
In principle that's harmless but code that doesn't can turn into a permit leak later.
Not all leaks are memory leaks.